# "no match for operator->* in pos ->* op"

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am getting the following error while compiling the below code. I am confused and am not able to figure out what is wrong here. Is the member function pointer de-referencing wrong?

Error:

```
#g++ fp.cpp
fp.cpp: In member function âvoid Y::callfptr(void (X::*)(int))â:
fp.cpp:33: error: no match for âoperator->*â in âpos ->* opâ
```

fp.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class B {
 // some base class
};

class X : public B {
 public:
  int z;
  void a(int a) {
    cout << "The value of a is "<< a << endl;
  }
  void f(int b) {
    cout << "The value of b is "<< b << endl;
  }
};

class Y : public B {
 public:
  int b;
  vector<X> vy;
  void c(void) {
   cout << "CLASS Y func c called" << endl;
  }
  void callfptr( void (X::*op)(int));
};

void Y::callfptr(void (X::*op) (int)) {
 vector<X>::iterator pos;
 for (pos = vy.begin(); pos != vy.end(); pos++) {
  (pos->*op) (10);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
(pos->*op) (10);
```

Do this:

```
((*pos).*op)(10);
```

Iterators are not required to provide an overload of `operator ->*`. If you really want to use `operator ->*` instead of `operator .*`, then you could do:

```
((pos.operator ->())->*op)(10)
```

But this is just more verbose.

A difference which may be relevant for your use case is that operator `->*` can be overloaded, whereas `operator .*` cannot.

Answer (score 3):

`->*` is `operator ->*`. You can use

```
pos.operator->()->*op
```

or simply

```
(*pos).*op
```